# How to conditionally link a library depending on target architecture using XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, linker

My application needs to link different libraries depending on whether I build a 32bit or a 64bit version. I am transitioning from a Makefile to XCode. In my Makefile, I could just list all libraries explicitly depending on the target architecture.

How do I do the same in XCode 4?

I have added all the libraries to link against in the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase, but XCode tries to link them all regardless of whether I select "My Mac 32-bit" or "My Mac 64-bit" as the build destination.